# React Native packager.js bug crashes development server?

Tags: javascript, android, windows, reactjs, react-native

It seems the development server that serves the JavaScript to the App has broken code (on Windows).

Calling this to run the development server: `node node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.js` works fine until the App requests the JavaScript Bundle. That causes the development server to crash:

The crash looks slightly different every time, here are some examples:

```
    <--- Last few GCs --->

      299789 ms: Scavenge 1401.1 (1455.6) -> 1401.1 (1455.6) MB, 7.4 / 0 ms (+ 2.0 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
      300662 ms: Mark-sweep 1401.1 (1455.6) -> 1401.0 (1455.6) MB, 872.8 / 1 ms (+ 3.0 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 2.0 ms) [last resort gc].
      301517 ms: Mark-sweep 1401.0 (1455.6) -> 1401.0 (1455.6) MB, 855.0 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


    <--- JS stacktrace --->

    ==== JS stack trace =========================================

    Security context: 00000394AB737349 <JS Object>
        1: join [path.js:~217] [pc=000000C79FE49004] (this=000003690CB64909 <an Object with map 000003B796023E19>)
        2: arguments adaptor frame: 3->0
        3: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [Y:\Mobile\node_modules\react-native\packager\react-packager\src\DependencyResolver\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:~226] [pc=000000C7A12131DA] (this=00000394AB704131 <undefined>,realModuleN...

    FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Another one:

```
    <--- JS stacktrace --->

    ==== JS stack trace =========================================

    Security context: 000000A2FB137349 <JS Object>
        1: split(aka split) [Y:\Mobile\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\core-js\modules\es6.regexp.split.js:7] [pc=000003ABD89C3ED4] (this=0000033DA680BFD9 <String[33]: \node_modules\regenerator/runtime>,separator=0000033DA680BF91
    <JS RegExp>,limit=000000A2FB104131 <undefined>)
        2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->2
        3: normalize [path.js:193] [pc=000003ABD8...

    FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

This makes it impossible to use React Native on Windows.

Please help to fix this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a fix, commented on the Github issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2787